# Operator- Overloading for a class

Tags: c++

In my project, the user enters 2 float number ( integer part, and decimal part, separating with (.) . the (+) operator overloaded successfully. But in (-), there is no error, but the program doesn't seem to work properly.the answer will be wrong, for instance, when ob1 = 216.20 and ob2=213.45 the output is : 3.-35 ( which is wrong)
or even when ob1=213.45 and ob2=216.20 the output is 9999999999999999997.25 .

Thank You

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std ;
class Google
{
private:
    int integer[20];
    int decimal[40];
public:
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &z,Google &t);
    Google operator-(Google T);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &r,Google &p);
};// End Of Google Class
istream &operator>>(istream &z,Google &t)
{
    char a[100];
    cout<<"\n"<<" Please Enter The Google Number, Sepatare with (.)"<<"\n";
    z.get(a ,99);
    z.get();
    char  *x , *y;
    x = strtok(a,".");
    //cout<<x<<"\n";
    y = strtok('\0'," ");
    //cout<<y<<"\n";
    int k1=strlen(x);
    //cout<<k1<<"\n";
    int k2=strlen(y);
    //cout<<k2<<"\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < 20-k1; i++)
    {
        t.integer[i] = 0 ;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for( int i = 20-k1; i < 20; i ++ )
    {
        t.integer[i] = x[j] - 48 ;
        j ++ ;
    }
    for( int i = k2 ; i < 40 ; i ++ )
    {
        t.decimal[i] = 0 ;
    }
    for( int i = 0 ; i < k2 ; i ++ )
    {
        t.decimal[i] = y[i] - 48 ;
    }
    // for (int i =0; i< k2 ; i++) {
    //cout<<"\n"<<t.decimal[i]<<"\n";
    //} Checking Out Outcome
    return z ;
}
Google Google::operator-(Google T)   {
    Google M1;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < 40 ; k++ )
    M1.decimal[k] = 0 ;
    for(int p = 0 ; p < 20 ; p ++ )
    M1.integer[p] = 0 ;
    for(int j = 39 ; j > 0 ; j -- )
    {
        if (this->decimal[j]<T.decimal[j])
        {
            this->decimal[j-1] -= 1 ;
            this->decimal[j] += 10 ; 
        }
        M1.decimal[j] = this->decimal[j] - T.decimal[j] ;
    }
    if (this->decimal[0]<T.decimal[0])
    {
        M1.integer[19] -= 1  ;
        M1.decimal[0]  +=  10 ;
    }
    M1.decimal[0] = this->decimal[0]- T.decimal[0] ;
    for(int i=19 ; i> 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (this->integer[i] < T.integer[i])
        {
            this->integer[i-1] -= 1  ;
            this->integer[i] +=  10 ;
        }
        M1.integer[i] = this->integer[i] - T.integer[i] ;
    }
    return M1;
} //end of Operator 
ostream & operator <<(ostream &r ,Google &p )
{
    int  k1 = 0 , k2 = 0 ;
    for( int  i = 0 ; p.integer[i] == 0 ; i ++ )
    k1 ++ ;
    for( int  i = k1 ; i < 20 ; i ++ ) 
    r << p.integer[i] ;
    if( !p.integer[19] )
    r << "0"  ;
    for( int  i = 39 ; p.decimal[i] == 0 ; i -- )
    k2 ++ ;
    cout<<"."  ;
    for( int  i = 0 ; i < 40 - k2 ; i ++ )
    r << p.decimal[i] ;
    if( !p.decimal[0] )
    r << "0"  ;
    return  r ;
}

void main () {
    Google ob1;
    Google ob2;
    cin>>ob1;
    cin>>ob2;
    cout<<"ob1 = " <<ob1<<"\n"<< "ob2 = " <<ob2<<"\n" <<endl;
    Google ob4;
    ob4 = ob1-ob2;
    cout<<"\n"<<"Result of (-) Will Be:"<<"\n";
    cout<<ob4;
    cout<< "\n";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please shrink down your code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue - this is really too much code to go through. Also, please properly format your code. For more information, see http://sscce.org (focus on **short**)

Comment: next, work on the indentation, remove the superfluos blank lines (not all, but 4 in a row are too much empty space), use a consistent style instead of changing where you put the braces every two lines. This code is all but ureadable.

Comment: +1 for a good attempt at an SSCCE!

Comment: +1 for listening to the comments and making an actual effort to reformat the code :)

Comment: I suggest you post this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to learn how to improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues that I've spotted.
When you do the subtraction for `decimal[0]` you subtract `1` from `M1` while for the other decimals you use `this`. Likely they both should be the same (probably `M1` since you don't want to modify the number stored in `this` when you subtract something from it). Take care that you don't lose the `-1` later on when you overwrite it with the new digit.

Another thing that you're doing is not handling negative numbers correctly. If you subtract 1 from 0 you code would fill the `integer` part 9's. This format is called 9's complement and basically to get the negative number you need to extract 9-integer[x] for each digit (including the decimal part). Another way to handle it would be to first compare the two numbers and if the result would be negative swap the operand (the result will be positive now) and change the sign.

The are probably other issues as well. Take a bunch of very simple examples and debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're doing Fixed-Point arithmetic here. It looks like you've got a problem where the carry/borrow doesn't propagate from the fractional part to the integer part correctly. (e.g. 5.222 - 0.223) Have you considered this case at all?

Three hints for you:

- Add a constructor to your class which clears the two arrays. That will avoid you having to do it explictly in the '-' operator or anywhere else.
- Consider having one array of digits rather than two, and just inserting/removing the decimal point at the time you input/output the number. This will make your algorithms simpler, and also make the code more maintainable.
- don't use 'magic numbers' like `20` throughout your code. define `static const int IntDigits=20;` as a private class member, and use that.